# Db problems with first heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My first app on heroku is having some issues:

The migration for the Users table went without a hitch on heroku, however loading the user's controller leads ot an error message. (Btw, this app is a scaffold, so I did not ass any custom code).

http://starapp.heroku.com/users

Since I am new to heroku, I am not sure how to even start finding out what went wrong. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

======================EDIT===========================

**The Model is working fine from the Rails Console.**

2011-10-08T14:36:34+00:00 heroku[router]: GET starapp.heroku.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=39ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-10-08T14:36:34+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users] miss
2011-10-08T14:36:34+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 70.16.214.90 - - [08/Oct/2011:07:36:34 -0700] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)" starapp.heroku.com

======================EDIT 2===========================

**This is what happened during the first attempted migration on heroku:**

C:\Users\admin\RubymineProjects\q>heroku rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adap
ter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

C:\Users\admin\RubymineProjects\q>

Comment: First step, check the log to see what's happening: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: The log does not reveal much about the db activity, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you develop on PostreSQL? If not, then it will help you to know that there are some subtle but important differences between SQLite/MySQL, and PostgreSQL. The main difference being the PSQL is a lot more strict in syntax. This can cause errors. http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL

Comment: hi bricker, this is a scaffold app, so no SQL specific code was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add pg to your Gemfile.

Comment: At least provide a link or something. [Heroku docs on installing the pg gem](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3).

Comment: I did this already. The database can be accessed through the model User with the heroku console, so there is no problem there.

Comment: This was the first error message. gem 'pg' was then added and the migration worked.